# Deploy to azure functions app sending all files to app files but not recognising my functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have tried to deploy a functions app to azure. The app deploys but then does not recognise I have functions.

```
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.documentintelligence import DocumentIntelligenceClient
from .feature_extraction import extract_section_headers


# Set up logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)


@app.route(route="HttpTrigger", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    document_url = req.params.get('documentUrl')
    if not document_url:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
            document_url = req_body.get('documentUrl')
        except ValueError:
            pass

    if not document_url:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a document URL in the query string or in the "
             "request body",
             status_code=400
        )

    # Azure credentials from environment variables
    endpoint = os.environ["DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_ENDPOINT"]
    key = os.environ["DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_KEY"]

    credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
    document_intelligence_client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(
        endpoint=endpoint,
        credential=credential
    )

    try:
        poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url(
            "prebuilt-layout", document_url)
        result = poller.result()

        # Extract section headers
        section_headers = extract_section_headers(result)
        logger.info(section_headers)

        return func.HttpResponse(
            body=str(section_headers),
            mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=200
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Failed to analyze document. Exception: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Failed to analyze document. Exception: {str(e)}",
            status_code=500
        )


app.register_functions(extract_section_headers)
```

I am also using another file called extract section headers where I have started the function like this:
from typing import List
import azure.functions as func

feature_extraction = func.Blueprint()

@feature_extraction.function_name("extract_section_headers")
def extract_section_headers(analyze_result) -> List[dict]:
"""
Extracts section headers from the analyzed document.

Also please find attached my project layout:
[Project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKSbi.png)

local.settings.json:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
      "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
      "DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_ENDPOINT": "https://smartformprocessor.cognitiveservices.azure.com/",
      "DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_KEY": "861e665469694f99acc152609d367628",
      "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
    }
  }
```

I am also experiencing this error, although I believe this is just related to local development.

```
**[2024-02-12T08:51:10.900Z] Reading functions metadata (Host)
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.900Z] 0 functions found (Host)
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.901Z] Reading functions metadata (Custom)
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.901Z] 1 functions found (Custom)
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.901Z] 0 functions loaded
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.901Z] Generating 0 job function(s)
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.904Z] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.904Z] HttpOptions
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.904Z] Initializing function HTTP routes
[2024-02-12T08:51:10.904Z] No HTTP routes mapped**
```

I am expecting the functions to be shown in the functions section of my azure portal. I have tried debugging locally and also deploying via github actions with a successful deployment but still not functions.

Comment: Follow the steps from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-python?pivots=python-mode-decorators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a V2 python function with below code in it and added the necessary packages in `requirements.txt` file.

**function_app.py**-

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import os
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential 
from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from feature_extraction import extract_section_headers

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    document_url = req.params.get('documentUrl')
    if not document_url:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            document_url = req_body.get('documentUrl')

    if not document_url:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a document URL in the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=200
        )
    # Azure credentials from environment variables
    endpoint = os.environ["DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_ENDPOINT"]
    key = os.environ["DOCUMENT_INTELLIGENCE_KEY"]

    credential = AzureKeyCredential(key)
    document_intelligence_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(
        endpoint=endpoint,
        credential=credential
    )
    
    try:
        poller = document_intelligence_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url(
            "prebuilt-read", document_url)
        result = poller.result()
        
        # Extract section headers
        section_headers = extract_section_headers(result)
        logging.info(section_headers)
        
        return func.HttpResponse(
            body=str(section_headers),
            mimetype="application/json",
            status_code=200
        )
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to analyze document. Exception: {str(e)}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            f"Failed to analyze document. Exception: {str(e)}",
            status_code=500
        )
```

`requirements.txt` file looks like below-

```
azure-functions
azure-ai-formrecognizer
azure-core
```

Then executed the function locally and got the expected output.

[image]

- In order to avoid the post deployment issues, you need to execute the function locally and then you deploy it to the function app.
- I deployed my code to function app using vs code and got successfully deployed response.

[image]

**Portal**-

[image]

Comment: I was able to deploy a functions app like this via vs code. However I wanted to be able to maintain the code using github actions. I have noticed that a .js file is created which looks very much like the v1 .json files. Could this be linked?

Comment: @TylerBMcCarthy You can raise new Qs with your current ask which can be addressed by the community.